# kafkajs run eachMessage is not fetching messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I'm trying to fetch messages from Kafka using kafkajs
I want to catch all messages into "messages" (an array)
config - the variable which hold the configs
Here is the function I'm using:

```
const { Kafka, logLevel } = require('kafkajs')
async function consume_messages(config) {
    const kafka = new Kafka({
        logLevel: logLevel.INFO,
        brokers: [config.broker],
        ssl: true,
        sasl: {
            mechanism: [config.mechanism], 
            username: config.Username,
            password: config.Password
        },
    })
    const topic = config.client_id
    const consumer = kafka.consumer({
        groupId: 'my-group', fromBeginning: true
    })
    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({
        topics: [topic],
        fromBeginning: true
    })
    let messages = []
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ message }) => {
             messages.push(message)
             console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE', JSON.parse(message.value), message.offset);
          }
        })
       
    })
    await consumer.disconnect();
    return messages ;
}
```

when I run it I get nothing the "messages" stays empty
However, when I removed the await from "await consumer.run({" -> "consumer.run({" it worked but only after the entire script ended.

How can I force it to run and to wait for all messages to be fetched?

Comment: Your consumer doesn't know how much time it should work, instead it's fired, works for some small period of time, and then is almost instantly disconnected. If your app is a backend, make the `await consumer.disconnect()` call a shutdown hook. If your app is just a kafka consumer -- let it work for some time, f.e. paste `await sleep(5 min)` before the `await consumer.disconnect()`.

Comment: You appear to be trying to block a Kafka consumer. Ideally, you don't do this and instead write callbacks into the location that actually needs the records rafter than using `return`. More importantly, Kafka topics should be thought of as endless, so don't "wait til the end"

Comment: I added a delay function just before "await consumer.disconnect()"
And removed the "await " from it

await delay(10000)
consumer.disconnect()


the delay function is:
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  } 

And it just wait 10 sec... and nothing happens...

Comment: Sadly I have added delay of 20 seconds after the run.
Not ideal

let messages = []
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            messages.push(JSON.parse(message.value))
            console.log(`Total messages so far : ${messages.length}\n`);
        }
    })

    await delay(20000)


The delay function:
function delay(time) {
    console.log(`\nwaiting ${time} seconds....\n`)
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to add a pause after the run() finction.
I must say I'm not happy about this solution since I'm forcing my side to wait fixed 5 seconds regardless to the results.

I'll be happy for a better solutions - but here it is:
I have added a delay function:

```
    function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

And then , after the run "await consumer.run(..." and before "consumer.disconnect()" I called it
Like this:

```
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ message }) => {
             messages.push(message)
             console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE', JSON.parse(message.value), message.offset);
          }
        })
           
        })
/*Here is where the code waits for messages to be pulled  */
       await delay(5000)
       consumer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a better solution?

Comment: nope....

I'm working with many APIs and this was the 1st time I hade to pull data from kafka..
For my needs - I wish they never used kafka...

Comment: i'm finding the same issue - essentially the `await consumer.run(...)` does not actually block, it seems to return immediately, and so the disconnect runs immediately after and then your function returns nothing 

Answer (score 0):

KafkaJS `await consumer.run` won't block, it just kicks off the process that fetches the messages and then returns immediately, which is ideal for long-running processes. However, blocking until certain messages arrive is a very common behavior in test setups.

Waiting for a specified delay after the `await consumer.run` should do the trick in many cases:

```js
await consumer.run({
  // ...
});

await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

await consumer.disconnect();
```

A more flexible approach could be returning another promise, from the `consumer_messages` function, which is only fulfilled within the `eachMessage` handler block based on a maximum number of messages, or a custom condition that can be provided from the outside as a high-order function.

For example, changing the provided snippet to support the above would look like the following:

```js
async function consume_messages(config, messagesMatcher) {
    // setup code omitted for brevity

    let handleResolve;
    let handleReject;
    let messages = [];
    await consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ message }) => {
            try {
                const value = JSON.parse(message.value);
                console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE', value, message.offset);
                messages.push(value);
                if (messagesMatcher(messages)) {
                    handleResolve(messages);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                handleReject(error);
            }
        }
    })

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        handleResolve = resolve;
        handleReject = reject;
    }).finally(async () => {
        console.log('disconnecting consumer');
        await consumer.disconnect();
    });
}
```

Then, the function can be accessed as:

```js
let messages = await consume_messages(
    config,
    (messages) => messages.length === 1
);
console.log(messages);
```